# Circuit Implementation of Dynamical Systems - Lorenz Equations (Failure Analysis)

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, noise, failure

Let me begin with the disclaimer: I am a mathematician and not an electrical engineer. That being said, surely I am missing something simple. For classroom demonstrations in dynamical systems, I have been constructing analogue computers from op-amp circuits. Some of the circuits are of my own design, and some are copied from other scientists. All of them have been successful except for this one, by Cuomo & Oppenheim, 1993, Physics Review Journal:

[image: Cuomo & Oppenheim - MIT 1993]

This circuit is designed to mimic the Lorenz Equations (rather, a re-scaled version thereof). The [x] are analog multipliers (AD633JN), and I am using NTE858M op amps. I have checked my work and I am convinced that I have built correctly. I have also verified the accuracy of the schematic, and I cannot find any discrepancy between the circuit and the corresponding dynamical system. The only output is a millivolts noise.

Why does this implementation fail?

Here is a link to the author's paper for more detailed information:

http://www.rle.mit.edu/dspg/documents/CircuitImplementation_000.pdf

Comment: Does the integrator output, w(t), need an initial condition, say, 2V?

Comment: I was considering this... maybe it needs an impulse to get it started.

Comment: Charge C3 at w(t) to around 2V (through a resistor) then switch off the charging voltage, and keep fingers crossed!

Comment: @Chu I will be back in the lab in about an hour, will certainly try this.

Comment: It didn't work. I'm going to modify the design to include only inverting sums. If you think of anything, please let me know.

Comment: You could simulate it using Multisim. But the circuit does seem to be faithful to the equations. Did you ground the other end of C3, at the op-amp negative input, when charging it? Normally, a double pole switch is used to set initial conditions.

Comment: I tried charging the caps, and even tried a driver. These should not be necessary because the only fixed points are repulsive; even a millivolt signal should have been sufficient initial condition to start the cycle. Maybe I built it wrong, or I'm missing something else. My next plan is to disconnect the loop and test each section with a driver, etc. I am convinced that the author's work is impeccable, so I must be doing something wrong. How much capacitance is in a breadboard?

Comment: Capacitance between adjacent tracks is about 2pF. (Wikipedia, breadboards). The reasons digital computers are widespread and not analogue computers to me explains why you are not getting the results you expect. Noise, non-linearities, differences among devices. I think at the least, simulations would be a good idea, with tests that assert expected behaviour for isolated sections of the circuit.

Comment: I suggest you verify that no opamp outputs are stuck high or low.

Comment: @reluctant mathematician, in my opinion the part values  (R5, R11, R15, R18, R20, C1,C2,C3) given in the linked article **don't correspond** to the described differential equations for ***u***, ***v*** and ***w*** and to mentioned parameters ***sigma*** =16, ***r*** =45.6 and ***b*** =4. I have analyzed the circuit and obtained different results (for the coefficients within the equations). Hence I doubt a bit that "*the author's work*" is so "*impeccable*" as you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here's is my thoughts I think that implementation might fail is because in the paper you reference, the author's use the device AD632AD multiplier while you are using the AD633JN multiplier. A quick glance through the datasheet and we can see that the AD632AD multiplier performance total error has maximum of +/-1 while the AD633JN has a multiplier performance total error has maximum of +/-2. Also the AD632 multiplier under the multiplier perfomance has a maximum Output Offset Voltage of +/-30mV while the AD633 has a maximum Output Offset Voltage of +/-50mV. It think that those differences between might be worth looking into because given the nature of chaotic system it might just be enough to modified the circuit behavior.

Comment: I fear that you may be right, but I am hoping not... the AD632 is too pricey. Also, 633 worked well for Van der Pol and Duffing oscillators. (Perhaps these were less sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

Please pardon it may be obvious but it seems that if you are using an oscilloscope to view the outputs be careful that you are operating in XY mode instead of just viewing each signal with respect to time.